# Replace a char in a string with another string?

Tags: java

I have a string. I want to replace a character in this string, with another string.
How do I do that please ?

For example i have `aaaaa` i want to replace the first '`a`' with "`bbbb`"

```
for(i=0; i<aString.length()-1; i++){
    if(aString.charAt(i)...some condition)
        charAt(i) replace with some other string
}
```

Thats what im trying to do

Comment: Would `replaceFirst` not do what you want?

Comment: If you want to replace a `char` with `string`, better use concatenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your specific problem( replacing the first 'a'):

> public String replaceFirst(String regex,
>                     String replacement)
>
> Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given
>   regular expression with the given replacement.

That is:

```
String s="aaaaa";
String res=s.replaceFirst("a","bbbb");
```

---

For a general solution:

> public StringBuilder replace(int start,
>                                int end,
>                                String str)
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> start - The beginning index, inclusive.
>
> end - The ending index, exclusive.
>
> str - String that will replace previous contents.
> ```

That is:

```
String s="aaaaa";
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s);
String res=sb.replace(0,1,"bbbb").toString();
```